# AWS password instead of key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm a total newbie when it comes to AWS. I'm trying to launch a Ubuntu instance and since I use a cloud IDE and don't to make things needlessly complicated I don't want to generate a key pair but rather a username/password, so I choose "continue without a key pair". I have to agree that I know that I'm not able to login without the username/password but it never gives me any...

What's the deal with this? What should I do?

Also, when I press connect it says:

> Instance is not associated with a key pair This instance is not
>   associated with a key pair. Without a key pair you will need to log
>   into this instance using a valid username and password combination.

But it never actually gives me any boxes to put in the username/password I don't have anyway. Why do they even have this function if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Continue without a key pair" means "you won't be able to connect to it".

AWS (and most hosting providers) require ssh keys, as the security of basic passwords is poor. Using keys isn't terribly difficult.

Comment: So why even be able to make it, and why say it needs a username/password if it's altogether impossible?

Comment: Note the wording, you'd need to use a *valid* (read this: *already existing and valid*) username and password combination...  it's not strictly altogether impossible if the machine image that you're using to launch the new instance already had valid username/password combinations embedded.  Such a setup would be a bad idea and isn't allowed on public machine images (such as the one you're almost certainly using to launch your instance) but is technically possible if you had built the source machine image yourself.

Comment: Good thought @Michael-sqlbot. As I was thinking about yeats's comment I realized it isn't really AWS, it's the creators of images. I suspect there are Windows instances and some Marketplace images that use a username.

Comment: There are reasons you might want it to be impossible for anybody to log into an instance. Perhaps you've set it to automatically configure itself and push logs to an external service. Then allowing any logins would be an unnecessary security risk.

Answer (score 1):

user is the generic username

you will have to access actions>instance settings>get system log on your initial instance launch

scroll down until you see the username and password. log in and change it

Comment: Great, It works for me, I've found the wordpress username and password. in the logs setup by bitnami in ec2-instance

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the generic username."
In the System Log, I see no trace of a password. I copy-pasted the System Log text into Notepad and **Ctrl + F**'d for "Password" and found no password. I **Ctrl + F**'d for "User" and found *"no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu."* So I guess `ubuntu` is the "generic username"??